# Removing Multiple Objects from Javascript Array Breaks Half Way Through

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, backbone.js

I have an Array of a few hundred JSON Objects...

```
var self.collection = [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object…]
```

Each one looks like this...

```
0: Object
   id: "25093712"
   name: "John Haberstich"
```

I'm iterating through the Array searching each Array.id to see if it matches any ids in a second Array...

```
   var fbContactIDs = ["1072980313", "2502342", "2509374", "2524864", "2531941"] 

   $.each(self.collection, function(index, k) {
        if (fbContactIDs.indexOf(k.id) > -1) {
            self.collection.splice(index, 1);
        };
    });
```

However this code only works to splice three of the Objects from the self.collection array and then it breaks and gives the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
```

The line that is causing the error is this one...

```
if (fbContactIDs.indexOf(k.id) > -1) {
```

Could anyone tell me what I'm dong wrong here?

Answer (score 5):

Because the length of collection will change, the trick is to loop from rear to front

```
for (var index = self.collection.length - 1; index >= 0; index--) {
    k = self.collection[index];
    if (fbContactIDs.indexOf(k.id) > -1) {
        self.collection.splice(index, 1);
    };
}
```

Comment: …or to use `.splice(index--, 1)`

Answer (score 1):

You should not change the length of an array while iterating over it.

What you're trying to do is **filtering** and there's a specific function for that. For example:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10].filter(function(x){ return (x&1) == 0; })
```

will return only even numbers.

In your case the solution could then simply be:

```
self.collection = self.collection.filter(function(k){
    return fbContactIDs.indexOf(k.id) > -1;
});
```

or, if others are keeping a reference to `self.collection` and you need to mutate it inplace:

```
self.collection.splice(0, self.collection.length,
                       self.collection.filter(function(k){
    return fbContactIDs.indexOf(k.id) > -1;
}));
```

If for some reason you like to process elements one at a time instead of using `filter` and you need to do this inplace a simple approach is the read-write one:

```
var wp = 0; // Write ptr
for (var rp=0; rp<L.length; rp++) {
    if (... i want to keep L[x] ...) {
        L[wp++] = L[rp];
    }
}
L.splice(wp);
```

removing elements from an array one at a time is an `O(n**2)` operation (because for each element you remove also all the following ones must be slided down a place), the read-write approach is instead `O(n)`.

Comment: @thg435: what are the advantages of `$.grep(x, f)` in respect to `x.filter(f)`?

Comment: I'd use grep for stylistic reasons.