# Unsetting javascript array in a loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
  $.each(current, function(index, value) {
     thisArray = JSON.parse(value);
     if (thisArray.ttl + thisArray.now > now()) {
        banned.push(thisArray.foodID);
     }
     else{
        current.splice(index,1);
     }
  });
```

There's a problem with the following line:

```
current.splice(index,1);
```

What happens is that it (probably) unsets the first case which fits the `else` condition and then when it has to happen again, the keys don't match anymore and it cannot unset anything else. It works once, but not in the following iterations.

Is there a fix for this?

Comment: You happen to have an array of JSON strings?

Comment: exact duplicate of [Removing Multiple Objects from Javascript Array Breaks Half Way Through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18260784/removing-multiple-objects-from-javascript-array-breaks-half-way-through). You are not allowed to mutate an array that is looped over by `each`

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regular `for` loop, and loop backwards:

```
for(var i=current.length-1; i>= 0; i--) {
   var thisArray = JSON.parse(current[i]);
   if (thisArray.ttl + thisArray.now > now()) {
      banned.push(thisArray.foodID);
   } else {
      current.splice(i, 1);
   }
});
```

Also it seems `thisArray` is actually an object, not an array...

Answer (score 0):

you can use regular for loop, but after splice, decrease index by 1

```
for(var i=0; i<current.length; i++){
    current.splice(i, 1); i--;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pay attention if you mutate an array (by moving objects) while it's being traversed because some element may get skipped like in your case.

When you call `current.splice(index, 1)` element `index` will be removed and element `index+1` will take its place. But then `index` will be incremented, thus skipping one element.

A better solution is IMO the read-write approach. You keep one index as the "read pointer" and you always increment it, and another index (the "write pointer") that is incremented only when you decide an element should be kept in the array:

```
var wp = 0;  // The "write pointer"
for (var rp=0; rp<a.length; rp++) {
    if (... i want to keep element a[rp] ...) {
        a[wp++] = a[rp];
    }
}
a.splice(wp); // Remove all elements after wp
```

This is a `o(N)` operation and will move each element at most once. Other approaches like starting from the end and using the same `splice(i, 1)` approach instead will keep moving all elements after `i` each time an element needs to be removed.